# Business logic for "follow" functionality. Problem in concurrency

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use asp.net core and entity framework. I had a task in the need to create a "follow" button.
At the moment, my model looks like this:

```
public class Following
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("FollowerId")]
    public string FollowerId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public bool IsFollowing { get; set; }
}
```

I have a follow and unfollow function, they look like this:

```
    public async Task<bool> Follow(string userId, string currentUserId)
            {
                var currentExist = await GetFollower(userId, currentUserId);
                // insert if new
                if (currentExist == null)
                {
                    var newFollower = new Following()
                    {
                        FollowerId = currentUserId,
                        UserId = userId,
                        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        IsFollowing = true
                    };
                    InsertFollower(newFollower);
                    // update counters
                    updateFollow(userId, currentUserId);
                    return true;
                }

                if (currentExist.IsFollowing)
                    return false;

                currentExist.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                currentExist.IsFollowing = true;
                context.Entry(currentExist);

                // update counters
                updateFollow(userId, currentUserId);

                return true;
            }

            public async Task<bool> UnFollow(string userId, string currentUserId)
            {
                // this I get user from db
                var exist = await GetFollower(userId, currentUserId);
                if (exist == null || !exist.IsFollowing) return false;

                exist.UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                exist.IsFollowing = false;
                context.Entry(exist).State = EntityState.Modified;

                updateUnFollow(userId, currentUserId);

                return true;
            }
```

Next, I call SaveChangesAsync()

This functions update user counters:

```
  private async Task updateFollow(string userId, string currentUserId)
    {
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UPDATE User SET FollowerCount = FollowerCount + 1 WHERE UserId = {0}", userId);
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UPDATE User SET FollowingCount = FollowingCount + 1 WHERE UserId = {0}", currentUserId);
    }

    private async Task updateUnFollow(string userId, string currentUserId)
    {
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UPDATE User SET FollowerCount = FollowerCount - 1 WHERE UserId = {0}", userId);
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("UPDATE User SET FollowingCount = FollowingCount - 1 WHERE UserId = {0}", currentUserId);
    }
```

The problem is that if I click on the "Follow" button many times. Unsubscribing and subscribing time after time. I will get an incorrect counter value and in addition sometimes a "Concurrency" error occurs. In other words, the counter value is sometimes lower than 1, and sometimes higher than 1, rarely when it is in the correct value of 1.
It makes no difference whether this line is deleted from the database or updated.

I would like this functionality to look like a "star" button like a github.

On the Internet I managed to find information about "rowversion". But I would like to hear the perfect solution for this task.

Comment: I would first aks myself, why store a redundant count value? Is it really a performance issue to do a count at runtime?

Comment: *But I would like to hear the perfect solution for this task.* that's a bit... broad.

Comment: @GertArnold Why keep it? To display this data on the user’s page and not to constantly count users when visiting the user’s page

Comment: @GertArnold Just like the like button here. I would like the same solution.

Comment: Did you *really* experience performance problems when querying the current counts? Databases tend to be very good at counting. Don't underestimate the headaches of redundancy.

Comment: So far then, it's premature optimization. For the rest, look at "optimistic concurrency".

Answer (score 1):

looking at this - I think the best way around it is to change the model.
You need to capture Followers & Followed.

Create a Many-to-many table to store the follower/followed.

```
CREATE TABLE followingTable 
(
FollowedUser Varchar(255), FollowingUser Varchar(255)
)
```

Then Your Follow Button Inserts into this table (if not there already)

Then rather than increment/decrementing the following/follower Counts
you calculate the value based off the Many-to_many Table.

EG:

```
UPDATE U

SET FollowerCount = Count(FollowingUser)
FROM
User u
join followingTable ft
on u.UserId = Ft.FollowedUser
```

The beauty of this approach is that if the User hits the button multiple times then it won't give a false value.